# Why is int[] treated as an rvalue?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Suppose I have this function:

```
void f(int*& ptr) {
//do something
}
```

When I try to do:

```
int array[3] = {};
f(array); //fails to compile, error array is rvalue
int* p = array;
f(p); //compiles
```

Why does the first case fail? Aren't arrays equivalent to pointers?

Comment: What the answers are leaving out, the actual problem: With the first call, you can´t assign some new address to the array.

Comment: _"Aren't arrays equivalent to pointers?"_ **NO**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, arrays aren't equivalent to pointers.

In the first case, the array has to be converted to a pointer. The result of a conversion is an *rvalue*, which can't bind to a non-const *lvalue* reference, hence the error.

In the second case, `p` is an *lvalue* denoting an object of the correct type, so the function call succeeds.

Answer (score 2):

```
int* p = array;
f(p);     // compiles
f(array); // (this compiles too!)
```

Arrays are *not* equivalent to pointers, but there is a special rule that says the name of an array will be automatically treated as a pointer to the first element of the array, when you pass it as a function argument, or when you initialise a pointer to it (so `int* p = array` is a shortcut for `int* p = &array[0]`).

Your example with `f(p)` is not interesting: you're just passing a pointer to the first element of the array, manually.

---

```
int array[3] = {};
f(array); //fails to compile, error array is rvalue
```

Here, the "special case" I talked about wants to apply (so the name `array` is again treated as `&array[0]`), but the function accepts an `int*&` not an `int*`. To understand why this fails, consider this:

```
#include <string>

void baz1(std::string& str) {}
void baz2(const std::string& str) {}

int main()
{
    // baz1("hello world!");
    // ^ Doesn't compile, because converting string literal
    //   to std::string would result in a *temporary*, and you
    //   may not bind a temporary to a reference-to-non-const

    baz2("hello world!");
    // ^ OK, because baz2 takes a reference-to-const
}
```

Or, the same problem:

```
void ecl(int& x) {}
void ipse(const int& x) {}

int main()
{
    // ecl(3);  // doesn't compile
    ipse(3);    // OK
}
```

So we can fix your program like so:

```
void f(int* const& ptr) {}
//          ^^^^^

int main()
{
    int array[3] = {};
    f(array);  // compiles!
}
```